# Does openBSD 5.6 supports PAM technology?

Tags: jaas, pam, openbsd

I have device with openBSD 5.6 installed. OpenSSH is integrated to this OS. As I understand from this [topic](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#3.15), to set up the PAM usage I have to do it at the build time. Is there any way to permanently enable PAM for this OS?

Also it might be a problem that even if I will enable it than [sshd](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config) function has no UsePAM keyword.

One more issue is that I need to use JAAS as PAM. Does anybody know how to set it up? I didn't found any posts or documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenBSD doesn't support PAM. The links contain information related to OpenSSH Portable (i.e. the version of OpenSSH used on Linux).